# The line with equation $y=4x+c$ is a tangent to the curve with equation $y=x^2-x-5$

Tags: calculus

> The line with equation $y=4x+c$ is a tangent to the curve with equation $y=x^2-x-5$. Find the value of $c$. 
>   I did it 
>   $y=x^2-x-5$ 
>   $4=2x-1$ 
>   $\frac{5}{2}=x$
>   
>   $x=\frac{5}{2}$ 
>   $=(\frac{5}{2})^2-\frac{5}{2}-5$
>   $=-\frac{5}{4}$

I got 
$-\frac{5}{4}$ but the right answer is $-\frac{45}{4}$

Help me out!

Comment: Since this is the umpteenth time I've had to retag your questions: "differential equations" do not mean what you think they mean. Questions like this could just be tagged [tag:calculus].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y = \left ({5 \over 2} \right )^2 - \left (5 \over 2 \right ) - 5 = 4\left (5 \over 2 \right ) + c \implies c = -45/4 $$

Alternatively, 
$$ 4x + c = x^2 - x - 5 \\
x^2 -5x - (5+c) = 0 \\$$
Tangency implies only one solution, therefore
$$ (-5)^2 - 4 (-(5+c)) = 0 \\
25+20  + 4c = 0 \\
c = -{45 \over 4}$$